# I know this is a very basic question but I am new to statistics

Tags: r, anova

How would you approach analysis of 6 groups representing a range of values, increasing in value against a continuous variable (number) ?

I am learning to use R right now. Would I have to use ANOVA?
Please let me know thank you

Comment: *How would you approach analysis of 6 groups representing a range of values, increasing in value against a continuous variable (number)?*---What do you mean six groups representing a range of values? Do you mean something like income split into ordered categories (e.g. income group 1: $10,000 - 20,000)? Please edit this into your question to ensure you get an accurate answer.

Comment: `How would you approach analysis of 6 groups representing a range of values, increasing in value against a continuous variable (number)?` Welcome to Cross Validated!  Does this mean that you have six scatterplots that you want to compare?